# Google Cloud + Linux TCP connection refused, what causes it?

Tags: linux, tcp, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have a VM instance "instance-1" running in Google Cloud (Linux instance-1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I have a service at port 1234, and when requested from "instance-1" itself:

```
curl localhost:1234
```

produces the expected response.

I have set up a firewall rule:

```
my-service Ingress  Apply to all     IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:1234   Allow 1000
```

This is identical, apart from port number and priority, to the default-allow-http rule.

But when attempting from the internet (aa.bb.cc.dd represents the public ip address of instance-1):

```
curl aa.bb.cc.dd:1234 --> curl: (7) Failed to connect to aa.bb.cc.dd port 1234: Connection refused
```

However

```
curl aa.bb.cc.dd:80
```

gives the expected response (not the same as the one I want on 1234)

As an experiment, I have made another cloud instance "instance-2" within the same subnetwork as "instance-1". It should be covered by the default rule:

```
default-allow-internal Ingress  Apply to all     IP ranges: 10.128.0.0/9 tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535, 1 more    Allow 65534
```

but its connection to instance-1:1234 also gets refused. Even after deleting my custom rule.

I don't think it's a local firewall problem on instance-1:

```
xxx@instance-1:~/.ssh$ sudo iptables -L Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination          Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination          Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination
```

So, I set up the same google cloud firewall rule for 2 different ports, but they one is accepted and the other refused. I don't quite see why. And as for additional firewalls on instance-1, I don't see any.

What can it be that refuses my connections to instance-1 from anywhere else than instance-1 itself?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services on linux can chose what address they listen on. If a service listens on `127.0.0.1`, then it will *only* accept local connections, even if there is no firewall. In order to accept connections on any interface, services should listen on `0.0.0.0`.

To test this, run `sudo netstat -lntp`, and look to see which address your service is listening on. If it says `127.0.0.1:1234`, then you will need to change it's listen address.  If it says `0.0.0.0:1234`, then it is a different issue.

Different software needs different steps to change the listen address. Apache uses the [`Listen` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen). The tomcat HTTP connector uses the [`address` Connector parameter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation). When coding yourself, specify the listen address when calling `bind` on the socket.

Comment: Thank you, that was bang on! It listens on the loopback interface only.
It seems I should have asked this on stackexchange, not here, hm sorry. But thank you very much for the answer!