# Google Cloud VM http connection problem - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: asp.net, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine, .net-6.0

I am trying to send Http request via Postman to .NET 6 App deployed on Google Cloud Debian VM.
After sending the request, I immediately receive the error - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

[image: Postman error]

I opened port 5000 that my App uses in Farewall section in Cloud console (screenshot below), but this did not change behavior, connection still refused. I guess that may be additional settings inside VM is needed because when I run netstat command to check list of opened ports I don't see 5000 or even 80 port in the list.
Need help to understand what I need to set up to get an opportunity to send http requests to Apps deployed in Google Cloud VM. I am not familiar with Google Cloud and even Linux, so could miss or don't understand something important.

Thank you in advance for help!

[image: Application console]

[image: VM Firewall rules in Cloud Console]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the same like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543606/google-cloud-linux-tcp-connection-refused-what-causes-it?rq=2). Need to deploy app on 0.0.0.0, but not on default localhost.